# Group homology and singular homology

Tags: homological-algebra, classifying-spaces

It is well-known that the singular homology of the classifying space of a group $G$ is isomorphic to the group homology of $G$ with coefficients in the trivial $G$-module $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $H_*(BG,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_*(G,\mathbb{Z})$. The question is whether there exists a chain level map (naturally defined) $C_*(G) \rightarrow C_*(BG)$ that lifts the above isomorphism in homology?

Comment: This is commented on in Ken Brown's bible on group cohomology, and attributed to Eilenberg-MacLane's 1945 paper *"Relations between homology and homotopy groups of spaces"*.

Comment: Depending on which chain complex you use to compute the homology of G and which model of BG you’re talking about, these might literally be the same.  They are for my favourite choices here...

Comment: To make clear what is already implicitly stated in the previous two comments: the original 1943 paper by Eilenberg and MacLane ([Relations between Homology and Homotopy Groups](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.29.5.155), Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 29:5 (1943), 155–158) _defined_ group cohomology as the cohomology of the classifying space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the answer is given in Eilenberg-MacLane's 1945 paper "Relations between homology and homotopy groups of spaces", as pointed out by Chris Gerig.